# Connect small diameter poly tubing to 4" PVC drain pipe

Tags: water, drain

I have a wastewater output from an RO system that I need to drain. The RO system is located in the basement, so the only drain pipe available is the 4" main drain for the house which is PVC.

The outlet water tubing supplied by the RO system vendor is 3/8" polypropylene tubing. How can I connect this to the 4" sewer drain pipe? I presumably want some kind of trap setup to prevent septic gases from getting into the RO system.

Note that the RO system is pressurized, at least on the input side of the membrane.

Comment: Think there are two ways to do it.  First is to get a big bag of fittings and reducers,  second is to get a 3/8 barb fitting and glue, and drill a hole in the 4 inch pipe.  For trap either bend poly or replace poly with bendable pipe/hose.

Comment: If the RO system is pressurized, you don't need a trap. In my area (midwest US) systems like this will drain into a floor drain near the water heater and HVAC. It's not a constant flow kind of a heavy drip/slow trickle and the floor drain has its own trap.

Comment: To make a proper answer we'd need to know if your city / town is subject to the International Residential Code. I'm referring to A112.1.2 "Air Gaps in Plumbing Systems." If so, you can't connect the RO brine line directly to a waste pipe regardless of the RO system pressure; it would have to be connected to an air gap device above a trap. Google "air gap device" for more info.

Comment: Especially if you need a trap anyway or the 4" line isn't already installed, you can put a T in the 4" line, attach the trap and use a barb/compression fitting to attach to a removable end cap.